# I'm getting outlines around all objects!

Tags: rendering, objects, 3d-view

I'm getting thin black outline around all objects which is also being rendered and the rendered image looks bad because of it! I don't have freestyle enabled or no cartoon modifier is enabled!Even tried disabling overlays but it is still appearing[image]

[image]

Comment: I don't see a black outline in either picture.

Comment: The pictures look like you're in solid viewport shading, as opposed to rendered. What happens if you switch to rendered?